# How can eosin be acidic and negative at the same time?

Tags: acid-base

The broadest acid-base definition is done by Lewis and he states that a lewis acid is:
"a compound or ionic species which can accept an electron pair from a donor compound."

And all the sources say that [eosin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eosin) is an acid and a negatively charged molecule.

I think eosin cannot accept a pair of electrons if it's already negatively charged, thus, it should be considered as a base.

A clarification on this subject would be perfect.

Comment: There are many examples of negatively charged acids. Look at [polyprotic acids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid#Polyprotic_acids). As examples with biological relevance, $\ce{H3PO4}$ is an acid, but $\ce{H2PO4^{-}}$ and $\ce{HPO4^{2-}}$ can also act as acids. Similarly, $\ce{H2CO3}$ is an acid, but $\ce{HCO3^{-}}$ can also act as an acid.

Comment: There is nothing unusual in being an acid and a base at the same time. Many organic molecules (for example, pretty much any peptide) are like that.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto That is true, but what proton do you see on that molecule that is acidic when the molecule is negatively charged? These things look more like *Lewis* acids to me (Michael acceptors, maybe, to be specific).

Comment: @SendersReagent do you mean the molecular structures of eosin? (at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eosin)

Comment: There are a lot of hydrogen atoms on aromatic rings. Can't they be ionized?

Comment: @m1clee Indeed I do. Aromatic protons are usually very acidic. I don't really see any in there that I would describe as acidic.

Comment: Aren't "Aromatic protons" the hydrogen atoms on ch=ch-ch=ch-ch=ch  benzene ring for instance? So there are aromatic protons? And you say that they are very acidic.  So I can't see any problem here.

Comment: By the way I am not a chemist and right now I am just trying to understand your question. So if you think I don't have some basic  knowledge based on my last two replies, I'd be very happy if you could adress them.

Comment: Geeez, there's only an bad wording on Wikipedia - the picture shows anions of the acid as they are important - it's an acid so it is present in dissociated form in diluted solutions.

Comment: And no those anions aren't acidic in water solution. I guess @Senders wanted to say "aren't usually". Also edited this article you're referring to. Check it as it is now.

Comment: @Mithoron If that's true biologists misuse the term "acid" all the  time. For instance they call dna, "nucleic acid" whereas it is always in an aquaus solution with tons of negative po3(-2) in it which are conjugate bases. So it must be nucleic base, if we use the terms in a correct, unconventional way.

Comment: @Mithoron Aren't usually* correct.

Comment: DNA is nucleic acid and caring only about it's conjugate base doesn't change that. Still it's usually more or less neutralized with various counterions, so one could say it's in form of a salt or tight ionic pair, like bonded eosin.